# JTable not returning selected row correctly

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable, selection

I am working with an extension of the DefaultTableModel as follows:

This is the NEW AchievementTableModel after updating it to reflect input from some answers.

```
public AchievementTableModel(Object[][] c, Object[] co) {
    super(c,co);
}
public boolean isCellEditable(int r, int c) {return false;}
public void replace(Object[][] c, Object[] co) {
    setDataVector(convertToVector(c), convertToVector(co));
    fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

My GUI is a JTable that has the following properties:

```
if(table==null)
    table = new JTable(model);
else
    table.setModel(model);
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
table.setSelectionMode(DefaultListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
table.getColumnModel().setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
```

I have a JComboBox that selects which data to display. The TableModel is updated with a call to model.replace(cells) and then runs through the above table creation code again.

When selecting a row in the GUI JTable, and printing the table.getSelectedRow() value, I ALWAYS get -1 after changing the table data with a model.replace(cells) call from the first selection, even if I reselect the first JComboBox option. Is there a reason for this that I'm missing? Should I change some code?

EDIT: The code has changed a lot over trying to answer this question so here is the updated code. The new AchievementTableModel is above.

This sets up the model and table to be viewed correctly and displayed in a ScrollPane

```
if(model==null)
    model = new AchievementTableModel(cells, columns);
else
    model.replace(cells, columns);
if(table==null) {
    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    table.setSelectionMode(DefaultListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    table.getColumnModel().setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
    table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
} else
    table.setModel(model);

column = table.getColumn(columns[0]);
column.setPreferredWidth(25);
column = table.getColumn(columns[1]);
column.setPreferredWidth(225);
column = table.getColumn(columns[2]);
column.setPreferredWidth(40);
table.doLayout();

add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: can you show the method where you are printing table.getSelectedRow(), please

Comment: There is a button with an action attached to it that relies on the getSelectedRow() method, and prints the selected row to System.out. I select a row and click the button, but always get the -1 output.

Comment: MMMhh You don't have to override all those methods. You're repeating what the super class already does and perhaps losing some listener in the progress. Comment all those methods and do what Clint suggested. Let's see what happens.

Comment: I removed all of the extra override methods that weren't needed so that the only things left are isCellEditable and replace. Then redid the constructor to super(c,co); and it didn't change anything.

Comment: What is the reason for calling table = new JTable, opposed to table.setModel(model)?

Comment: This has been changed, updating the source in the question

Comment: Don't drop the "{" in the single statements if/else EVER!!!! don't be lazy, it will bite you some day very veeeery deeply and it hurts... http://bit.ly/16pOwS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldnt reinitialize your table with a new JTable after you call replace.  the fireTableDataChanged() method will alert your existing table that it should repaint.  what is happening is that you are looking at the table that you put into the panel, but you are changing the variable to a different instance of JTable.  When you query that new, but not visible table, it will give you -1 for the selected row count.    it might be helpful if you edit your post to display what is going on in that area of the code.

**2nd edit:**

instead of this:

```
  if(model==null)
    model = new AchievementTableModel(cells, columns);
  else
    model.replace(cells, columns);
  if(table==null) {
    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    table.setSelectionMode(DefaultListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    table.getColumnModel().setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
    table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
  } else
    table.setModel(model);

  column = table.getColumn(columns[0]);
  column.setPreferredWidth(25);
  column = table.getColumn(columns[1]);
  column.setPreferredWidth(225);
  column = table.getColumn(columns[2]);
  column.setPreferredWidth(40);
  table.doLayout();

  add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

do this instead:

```
 if(model==null) {
    model = new AchievementTableModel(cells, columns);
 } else {
    model.setDataVector(cells, columns);
 }
 if(table==null) {
    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    table.setSelectionMode(DefaultListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    table.getColumnModel().setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
    table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);

    column = table.getColumn(columns[0]);
    column.setPreferredWidth(25);
    column = table.getColumn(columns[1]);
    column.setPreferredWidth(225);
    column = table.getColumn(columns[2]);
    column.setPreferredWidth(40);
    table.doLayout();

    add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
   } else {
    table.setModel(model);
   }
```

you dont need to add the table to a new scrollpane and re-add it to the panel on each model change.

Comment: If I remove this recreating of the JTable, the table becomes empty when I switch the model. What should I use to make the table reappear?

Comment: The columns disappear as well.

Comment: it sounds as if you are clearing out your table model as well.  to get this working, what you could do is to create a new table model and instead of creating a new JTable, you could call setModel() on the table.

Comment: I set the JTable to setModel instead of new JTable after a null check and made a new model instead. This did not fix the problem, everything still disappears.

Comment: are you still calling replace()?  are you creating a new AchievementTableModel every time you change the combo?

Comment: Making a new model with the new data instead of calling replace.

Comment: I copied the layout settings instead of moving them and all is well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now I'm interested

It looks like you have to really really clean up your code because there are a lot of reference all around.

The reason you are not seeing the table with a selected index is because each time you create a new `JTable` the method where you print the selected record still points to the original.  Since you're displaying now a "newly" created table the old one prints `-1`.

The reason you get empty table when using the `DefaultTableModel` is because the vectors are `null` ( perhaps obtained from the combo ) and thus  both the data and the headers disappear from the table.

You don't need a  subclass if you're using `Object[][]` as data anyway.

So here is a somehow simpler test class that you can see to correct yours.

I test it with both, your custom **`TableModel`** and the **`DefaultTableModel`**

This has nothing to do with your custom table model but the way you're using your references.

I hope this helps.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Test { 

    private DefaultTableModel tableModel = null;
    //private AchievementTableModel tableModel = null;
    private Object []   headers = new Object[]{"Name", "Last Name"};
    private Object [][] data;
    private Object [][] dataA = new Object[][]{{"Oscar","Reyes"},{"John","Doe"}};
    private Object [][] dataB = new Object[][]{{"Color","Green"},{"Thing","Car"}};
    private JTable table;


    public static void main( String [] args ) { 
        Test test = new Test();
        test.main();
    }
    public void main() { 
        // Create the frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        // Create the unique table.
        table = new JTable();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane( table ));

        // Add two buttons
        frame.add( new JPanel(){{ 
            // swap table model button ( simulates combo )
            add(new JButton("Change Table model"){{
                addActionListener( new ActionListener() { 
                    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) { 
                        if( tableModel == null ) { 
                            data = dataA;
                            tableModel = new DefaultTableModel( data, headers );
                            //tableModel = new AchievementTableModel( data, headers );
                            table.setModel( tableModel );
                        } else { 
                            data = data == dataA ? dataB : dataA;
                            tableModel.setDataVector( data, headers );
                            //tableModel.replace( data ); // not needed DefaultTableModel already has it.

                        }
                    }
                });
            }});
            // and print selectedRow button
            add( new JButton("Print selected row"){{
                addActionListener( new ActionListener() { 
                    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) { 
                        System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());
                    }
                });
            }});

        }}, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // show the frame
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

}
```

Your subclass unchanged.

```
class AchievementTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    public AchievementTableModel(Object[][] c, Object[] co) {
        super.dataVector = super.convertToVector(c);
        super.columnIdentifiers = super.convertToVector(co);
    }
    public int getColumnCount() {return super.columnIdentifiers.size();}
    public int getRowCount() {return super.dataVector.size();}
    public String getColumnName(int c) {return (String)super.columnIdentifiers.get(c);}
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object getValueAt(int r, int c) {return ((Vector<Object>)super.dataVector.get(r)).get(c);}
    public boolean isCellEditable(int r, int c) {return false;}
    public void replace(Object[][] c) {
        super.dataVector = super.convertToVector(c);
        super.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

Try it and see how it doesn't lose the table reference and always print the correct `selectedRow`.

[image]

Compare it with your code and fix it from there.

Comment: I'm going to post my updated code because so much has changed in the process of trying to solve this problem. After that I'll see what changes I can make from your example.

Comment: Yeap. Clean it up a bit ( removing sensitive information ) and post it. I bet it is a very easy to fix.

Comment: The code has been updated in the original post, please take a look. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

When it swaps out the data its removing the selection (since the index is now different), you'll need recalculate the selection and set it programmatically.

I'll point out that in my experience, this is why I tend to extend `AbstractTableModel` or out right implement my own `TableModel` interface from the ground up. Modifying the backing data reference as here, always causes a million problems IMHO.

Comment: I'm selecting again after the data is swapped with the replace(cells) call, so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: You're selecting them again as a user after the replace(cells) call, and it still returns an index of -1?

Comment: It returns the correct index only before I call replace, but after will always return -1, even after selecting many different rows in the JTable

Comment: "Modifying the backing data reference as here, always causes a million problems IMHO." +1, me too

Comment: I would do this, but it seems like there is a lot of behind the scenes work in the transition from the AbstractTableModel to the DefaultTableModel. Could you tell me which parts would need to be changed and/or how? This would be a great help.

Comment: I guess it depends on how much of that functionality you need of course! 90% of the time for me I only need to be able to addRow() and sometimes moveRow(). I'll admit that if you need to be able to add columns as well as rows it gets more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using

super.setDataVector(Vector dataVector, Vector ColumnNames);

```
javax.​swing.​table.​DefaultTableModel
public void setDataVector(Vector dataVector, Vector columnIdentifiers)
```

> From JavaDoc
>
> Replaces the current dataVector
>   instance variable with the new Vector
>   of rows, dataVector. Each row is
>   represented in dataVector as a Vector
>   of Object values. columnIdentifiers
>   are the names of the new columns. The
>   first name in columnIdentifiers is
>   mapped to column 0 in dataVector. Each
>   row in dataVector is adjusted to match
>   the number of columns in
>   columnIdentifiers either by truncating
>   the Vector if it is too long, or
>   adding null values if it is too short.
>   Note that passing in a null value for
>   dataVector results in unspecified
>   behavior, an possibly an exception.
>   Parameters: dataVector - the new data
>   vector columnIdentifiers - the names
>   of the columns

Comment: I tried changing the replace method to this:
public void replace(Object[][] c, Object[] co) {
  setDataVector(convertToVector(c), convertToVector(co));
  fireTableDataChanged();
 }

and that did not fix the problem.

Comment: When you call convertToVector, does it convert it to a vector of vectors? or a vector of arrays?

Comment: There is one for each, meant for the data and column names respectively.

Answer (score 0):

When you reorder a JTable you need to keep track of the original indexes in the TableModel for your data, not the current indexes on the JTable.  Visually the table may have shifted but the underlying data model has not.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the TableModel is changed when I change all the data cells, fireTableDataChanged() is called and I create a new JTable with the updated model.

Comment: do you create a new JTable or just reset the model?

Comment: I call model.replace(cells) and immediately after call table = new JTable(model)

Comment: See below, I don't want this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like when changing your selection is lost.

Does "getSelectedRow()" return anything "BEFORE" you change the model?

If so, then hold that index, change the model and then set that index again.

Probably you need to use a custom  [ListSelectionModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) for that

Comment: It does return the correct information before the model changes, but I don't want the behavior of something being selected based on what was selected before. When the model is changed, I want the user to have to select a new row. In my testing, selecting a row after updating the model and making a new table will always give a -1 regardless of the data or selection.

Comment: Ohh I get it!!.. It seems like the listener keeps looking at the old table model instead of the new one. Try looking around that.  Inspect around the ListSelectionListener and see what or where is that pointing.  Also, don't access super.dataVector directly there should be an accessor for that.

Comment: When you ask for the index do you ask current table or accidentally the old table?

Comment: I only keep one reference, so it has to be the current table.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I thought of, when you do `table= new JTable(model);` you are changing the table that the variable 'table' is referring to, however that may not automatically cause the new table to be rendered.

If you table is contained within a ScrollPane, you may need to call `ScrollPane.setViewportView(table);`

Comment: I tried adding the line of code you suggested, but this didn't affect the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of getting a -1 always for getSelectedRow(). The problem could have got solved by now. Nonetheless, posting the code which fixed my problem:

```
final int selectedRowIndex = table.rowAtPoint(mouseEvent.getPoint());
final int modelRowIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRowIndex);
```